# Multipe ajax calls in parallel and dispatching redux actions after success leads to "Uncaught Error: Actions must be plain objects"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, rxjs, redux-observable

I am new to rxjs and redux-observable. Trying to create an epic that allows me to do multiple parallel ajax calls and dispatches respective actions on success:

```
const loadPosters = (action$) => action$.pipe(
  ofType(Types.LOAD_FILMS_SUCCESS),
  switchMap(({ films }) =>
    forkJoin(films.map(film =>
      ajax
      .getJSON(`https://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie?query=${film.title}`)
      .pipe(
        map(response => {
          const [result] = response.results;
          const poster = `http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500/${result.poster_path}`;
          return Creators.savePoster(film, poster);
        })
      ),
    ))
  ),
);
```

`Creators.savePoster()` is an action creator for an action named `SAVE_POSTER`. But, whenever i run my application, no such action is dispatched. Instead i get an error message in browser console:

> Uncaught Error: Actions must be plain objects. Use custom middleware
>   for async actions.

### edit

Tried a simplified version without `forkJoin`, sadly yielding the same result:

```
const loadPosters = (action$) => action$.pipe(
  ofType(Types.INIT_SUCCESS),
  mergeMap(({ films }) =>
    films.map(film =>
      ajax
      .getJSON(`https://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie?query=${film.title}`)
      .pipe(
        map(response => {
          const [result] = response.results;
          const poster = `http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500/${result.poster_path}`;
          console.log(Creators.savePoster(film, poster));
          return Creators.savePoster(film, poster);
        })
      )
    ),
  ),
);
```

## Appendix

Just for reference, I have another epic which does a simple ajax call which works fine:

```
const loadFilms = action$ => action$.pipe(
  ofType(Types.INIT_REQUEST),
  mergeMap(() =>
    ajax
    .getJSON('https://star-wars-api.herokuapp.com/films')
    .pipe(
      map(response => Creators.initSuccess(response))
    ),
  ),
);
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that i don't return an Observable in my inner map. Changing:

```
return Creators.savePoster(film, poster);
```

to

```
return of(Creators.savePoster(film, poster));
```

makes it work.

By the way, if used with `forkJoin` it's also possible (and in my case better) to take the mapped results after all requests resolved and dispatch a single action instead of multiple ones:

```
const loadPosters = (action$) => action$.pipe(
  ofType(Types.INIT_SUCCESS),
  mergeMap(({ films }) =>
    forkJoin(
      films.map(film =>
        ajax
        .getJSON(`https://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie?query=${film.title}`)
        .pipe(
          map(response => ({ film, response }))
        )
      ),
    )
  ),
  mergeMap(data => {
    const posters = data.reduce((acc, { film, response}) => ({
      ...acc,
      [film.id]: `http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500/${response.results[0].poster_path}`,
    }), {});
    return of(Creators.savePosters(posters));
  })
);
```

In fact this is my favorite solution so far.

Comment: This is great, exactly what I was looking for :)
However I have an issue for failed ajax calls, do you know how to dispatch success action for each successful call with valid response and failure action for the failed ajax response?

I even tried combineLatest but it didn't work! Any clue, possibly?

Thanks